# intersect cast error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried the below but the intersect is not working with following errors
The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your tables contain `Text` type of data you have to convert it to the `varchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) They mention that,

> The query specification or expression cannot return xml, text, ntext,
>   image, or nonbinary CLR user-defined type columns because these data
>   types are not comparable.

Use something like `cast(textcolumnname as nvarchar(2000))` as `textcolumnname` instead of `text` field names.

I don't think there is any other way to do it if you want to use the `INTERSECT` you have to convert the datatype to the `varchar`.
The Other way is use the `INNER JOIN` with `DISTINCT` that will give you the same result as the `INTERSECT`. 
[Here is the detail description how to achive intersect with Inner join](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/03/sql-server-2005-difference-between-intersect-and-inner-join-intersect-vs-inner-join/)

Comment: I can't afford to alter table column datatype as there are too many of them. Any way to change the datatype to varchar at run time? i am searching online on this too

Comment: use CAST(textcol as varchar(8000))

Comment: I created the TEMP table and removed all the TEXT columns :)